# The getter updateEmail was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling updateEmail

Tags: flutter, dart

[Here are My Files][1]
[1]: http://www.mediafire.com/folder/2nx90ehvydwwh/Flutter

```
 void updateEmail(String email) {
updateWith(email: email);
```

}

Comment: When I am trying to navigate to LoginForm page From Sign_in_page this Error is Throwned

Comment: hi dear please try to provide code instead of sending user to site to check your code. if you placed your code in the question and try to explain your problem then I will be willing to help.

Comment: Also, if you have anything new to add, don't comment here instead update your post